# Как сделать чтобы нули считались один раз из разных позиций, а при повторений нуля в данной позиций пропускались?

Tags: c++

Из файла считывается по символьно вот такая информация
[image: Данные из файла]

Нужно посчитать нули по одному разу без повторений в их место положения. То есть в этом примере должна быть получена цифра 4, но в место этого получается 5.  Мысль заключалась в том что я могу посчитать все строки по отдельности, поскольку знаю что следующая нужная строчка будет через +4;
Написал вот такой код: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при подсчете он считает все нули, даже повторяющиеся. Пробовал добавить цикл for но результат не удачный. Возможно я просто что-то не понимаю по этому буду рад помощи.

P.S: Извиняюсь за оформление, поскольку пишу первый раз на форуме.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, не вижу в коде где вообще вы подсчитываете свои нули для разных позиций. imho для такого подсчета можно использовать битовый вектор , индексируемый переменной `Nomersimvola`,  инициализируемый нулями и в нем вы устанавливаете в единицу бит с индексом `Nomersimvola`  каждый раз, когда `h` == '0'. В конце считаете число ненулевых бит. Конечно, можно их подсчитывать и по ходу установки бит в 1

Comment: Приведите код и данные в текстовом виде, а не скрином.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо записывать в массив индекс на котором ты находишь нуль. При просмотре каждой следующей строки должно работать условие: не рассматривать индексы равные элементам массива.